# is there any way to learn uri has no image react-native

Tags: react-native

I am developing a e-commerce app and some products does not have pictures and because of that sometimes ımage components looks empty. It looks bad. (To get pictures i am using uri.)

My question is how can i know if there isn't a picture on that uri?

```
<FastImage
          source={{
            uri: photoUri,
            priority: FastImage.priority.high,
          }}
          style={styles.logo}
        />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try react-native-elements, it will show PlaceholderImage when uri error

```
import { Image as ImageElement } from 'react-native-elements'
import { Image } from 'react-native'

<ImageElement
   style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
   source={{ uri: reduceImageSize(item.image, width) }}
   PlaceholderContent={(
     <Image source={require('image-placeholder.png')} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
   )}
 />
```